# Getting an error saying "invalid rowid"

Tags: plsql

please help me with this "for update of" and "current of" clause in the cursors... though the cursor is able to fetch the records getting an error saying invalid rowid.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR C_EMP IS SELECT * FROM emp FOR UPDATE OF SAL;--LOCKING MEANS WE CANNOT MAKE ANY CHANGES ON THIS COLUMN WHILE THIS CODE IS RUNNING
BEGIN
  FOR R_EMP IN C_EMP LOOP
  IF R_EMP.SAL<5000 AND C_EMP%FOUND THEN
  UPDATE EMP2 SET SAL=SAL*1.1 WHERE CURRENT OF C_EMP;
  END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: assuming you are really wanted to update ANOTHER table (EMP2) and not EMP, then you cannot use `where current of` to update another table, as the rowid won't match. Where current of means "for the rowid we are processing" . Instead you would have to join on the right columns instead of that clause.

Comment: Thanks @DazzaL... issue resolved ... cursor on one table and row id on another table what a b***s*** mistake i made... thanks for finding out

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are really wanted to update ANOTHER table (EMP2) and not EMP, then you cannot use where current of to update another table, as the rowid won't match.

Where current of means "for the rowid we are processing" . Instead you would have to join on the right columns instead of that clause